# Assign values in matrix via indexing

Tags: python, arrays, r, numpy, rpy2

from R I am used to assign a simple value to a matrix
via using indexing like:

```
> mat <- matrix(NA,2,3)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
> mat[1,2] <- 12
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   12   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
>
```

Now I am have to run some scripts in Python and want to collect
values in 2D matrices as well. The matrices should have column and rownames
and I want to access them also via an index.
So far I thought about two ways:

- Either using RPy and doing it the way I am used to like in R,
  although I don't know how indexing command is working with RPy yet.

like:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

names = ['A','B','C']
dimnames = robjects.r['list'](names,names) 
mat = robjects.r['matrix'](NA, nrow = len(names), ncol=len(names), dimnames = dimnames)

# and here how to index and assign e.g. the value 12 to the cell mat["A","B"]??
```

- Or to use a Python native NumPy array which might be a cleaner solution. At the moment I just don't know how to create a matrix/array with the names list and how to assign values afterwards with an index.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you mean this to be a character array? If not, use `NA` not `"NA"`.

Comment: Of course, you're right this should be NA

Comment: I suspect you'll need `robjects.NA_Real` in the python code not `NA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [DataFrame datatype from pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe), might be for you.

```
import pandas
matrix = pandas.DataFrame(index=['a','b','c'], columns=['one','two'])
```

returns

```
   one  two
a  NaN  NaN
b  NaN  NaN
c  NaN  NaN
```

You can change entries: `matrix['one']['a']=1`, as well as other familiar numpy operations (as described in the [above link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe)).

Comment: Thats working perfectly so far. It is very easy to create the dataframe from its column and rownames with: pandas.DataFrame(index=names, columns=names) where names is referring to a python list of the names.

Comment: @Johannes Glad you like it, I am just getting started with it (having found it last night), so didn't realise you could do it like that! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to map row/column names into indices.

```
names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
idx = range(0, len(names))
d = dict((key, value) for (key, value) in zip(names, idx))
```

and then use it to access elements in the matrix,

```
mat[d['A'], d['B']] = 12
```

As far as I could tell from `rpy2`'s documentation, that should work; if it doesn't,
maybe the following syntax is more appropriate:

```
mat.rx(d('A'), d('B'))
```